# Different way showing a subgroup is a subgroup of another subgroup

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, alternative-proof

http://crazyproject.wordpress.com/2010/04/11/subgroups-and-quotient-groups-of-solvable-groups-are-solvable/

Lemma 1: Let $G$ be a group and let $H,K,N \leq G$ with $N$ normal in $H$. Then $N \cap K$ is normal in $H \cap K$. Proof: Let $a \in H \cap K$. Then $a(N \cap K) = aN \cap aK = Na \cap Ka = (N \cap K)a $because $a \in H$ and $a \in K$.

Throughtout the link they use this method :$a(N \cap K) = aN \cap aK = Na \cap Ka = (N \cap K)a$ to show that a certain subgroup is a subgroup of another subgroup.

I never seen this before.

In this proof I would have done something like this:

$N\cap K$ is normal since the intersection of a normal subgroup and subgroup is normal.

Let $a\in N\cap K$ then $a\in N $and $ a\in K$. $N\leq H$ so $a\in H$ too. So we have $a\in H\cap K$. Thus $N \cap K \trianglelefteq H \cap K$.

Can anyone explain why showing that $a\in H\cap K$ commutes with $N\cap K$

$$a(N \cap K) = aN \cap aK = Na \cap Ka = (N \cap K)a$$

implies $N\cap K \leq H\cap K$
.

Thanks :D I appreciate it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $x\in N\cap K$. Then $a(N\cap K) = (N\cap K)a$ means that $a(N\cap K)a^{-1} = N\cap K$, i.e., that $axa^{-1} \in N\cap K$, the exact condition for normality.